# Is there a hotkey to speed up the repetitive commits in Eclipse (or a general windows GUI macro tool)?

Tags: windows, eclipse, macros, eclipse-pdt

I am making numerous, minute changes to .php files in Eclipse PDT then committing them and testing on the server.

The repetitive six-step commit process is getting tedious:

```
right-click
team
Commit...
click "choose previously selected comment"
select in list
click OK
```

Does anyone know of a hotkey or other process to expedite this?

**UPDATE:** does anyone know of a general hotkey macro tool for windows applications which would allow me to program a macro that would make these 6 clicks for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I've been able to do is create a key binding for 'Commit' (under Preferences... General->Keys).  Then you just need to click on the project and hit a key combination, which saves the whole right-click->Team->Commit... process.

If you just want to check in the file you are editing, you don't have to click anywhere, just hit the key combination, and the commit dialog pops up to commit the current file.

Answer (score 1):

In  eclipse you can choose to either commit one file or the entire project.

To commit the entire project, right click on the project in your resource view, and choose Team->Commit.

If you want to preview the changes choose Team->Synchronize, which will show you what files are changed, and gives you a quick preview of the diffs in both incoming and outgoing mode.

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of Eclipse (or maybe some versions of Subclipse -- are you using SVN?) there was a toolbar button that you could click.  It would eliminate the first 2 or 3 steps of your commit process.  Maybe you can find that button on the toolbar editor (or perspective editor, or whatever they call it... it's been a while since I've used it).

Also, IMHO, you shouldn't be committing and THEN testing.  You'll find things run a lot smoother if you test locally, then commit (and test again in a QA type system...).  You probably already know that, so I'm going to assume there's a strange reason you can't test locally.

Comment: There are two (at least) plugins that provide SVN integration for Eclipse.  One is Subclipse, the other is something I can't remember right now.  I think I was using Subclipse when I found that button, but it could have been the other.  Which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I find that right-clicking the project or file in the Package Explorer is the most time consuming part of this repetitive process.

Mostly I make related changes in multiple files, then synchronize the whole project. The first step to making the whole process accelerated via hotkeys is to bind a key combination to "Synchronize with repository...". For Eclipse 3.5 on OSX, the hotkey can be bound by going to Eclipse->Preferences->General->Keys. Then search for "Synchronize" in the text filter. I bind control-s as synchronize.

Once a hotkey is bound for Synchro... , hitting the hotkey will synchronize the file in your active editor, or the selected files in the project explorer, if the project explorer is active.

To rapidly put focus in to the project explorer, hit, on OSX, command-F6 to cycle to the project explorer. Another way, if focus is in an editor view, is to hit cmd-alt-W (Show In...) and then select "Project Explorer" from the popup. Sorry for the OSX shortcuts. If you look in the Keys area mentioned earlier, you should be able to find the relevant hotkey for cycling views.

So we've sped up part of the process, but it would still be nice to have a rapid way of selecting the whole project. The easiest way is a hack- just start typing the name of your project while in the project explorer. If the name isn't unique enough, prepend a 'Z' to it or something so that just they keystroke 'z' will select the whole project. Then hit your Synchro... hotkey to synch the whole project.

Okay, so it takes quite a few hotkeys to synch the whole project, almost like playing a progression of guitar chords or doing a sweet combo in Tekken, but honestly the sequence of hotkeys can all be pushed in less than the time it takes to move your hand to the mouse. Perhaps binding a macro to the entire sequence would make it uber convenient.